# How to add automatic rating bar in Android

Tags: android, dialog, alert, rating, ratingbar

Have you ever seen the kind of box that automatically appears while using apps, that asks the user to rate the app and contains options like not now, never and remind me later?

How can I add such a dialog? I want the dialog to be display either on the 5th day after the app has been installed or on the 7th run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a custom dialog together with simple logic to keep a track of number of times user has logged in, user behaviour and accordingly show rating dialog. In case you want to use precompiled libraries for this task, you can use the following open source libraries along with your source code.

1. https://github.com/delight-im/AppRater
2. https://github.com/TimotheeJeannin/AppRate